# Taking Tallis Gadol into Bathroom

Tags: halacha

Generally Talis Gadol is wrapped only for prayer, not as a simple jacket. If someone has to wash his talis gadol, but the only place he can wash and dry it in his apartment is in the bathroom, can one take a tallis gadol into a bathroom or the like to be washed?

Comment: “May one enter the Tallis into the washroom or bathtub in order to be washed?[13]

Practically, one may be lenient to do so, if necessary.” I am unfamiliar with the source:   https://shulchanaruchharav.com/entering-with-tzitzis-tallis-gartel-and-kittle-into-a-bathroom-or-mikveh/

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) yds and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: In SA OC 21.3 you can see in Taz, Mishna Berura and Caf HAchayim that we cannot go to toilets wearing the Talit Gadol. But to whash it I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The Piskei Teshuvos 21:footnote 50 addresses this and writes that it is permissible to wash a talis in a restroom even if it has a toilet since the achronim held that there is no ruach raah in such a place.

text of Piskei Tesuvos:

[image]

In addition, Rav Ahron Mordechai Green (Yalkut Halichos Tzitzis 22) also concludes that it would be permitted.

Text of Yalkut Halichos Tzitzis 22:

[image]

Comment: +1 for a source discussing this. However, according to him it should allowed to be worn in there too, not just washed. That is seemingly contradictory in his words and not common practice.

Comment: see my added source which brings the Matteh Moshe, the MB is also mashma like that.

Comment: Nice source again. But I don't think the mb can be said to be mashma either way. Remember up until recently being mashtin could mean on a wall in the street, the word doesn't imply going into a bathroom. These sources both are working with the assumption one can wear their taalis into the bathroom which seemingly nobody does. On the other hand people do give their taleisim to the local nonjewish cleaners so go figure.

Comment: either way yesih al ma lsmoch,  I have seen people go into a bathroom with a kittel which is same thing as a talis ,it seems people do not do it since it is easy to take off ones talis as opposed to the kittel.

Comment: True point about the Kittel, but they seem to be the minority as most take it off. But for the ones who leave it on, it may just be ignorance. Some people, teenage boys in Yeshivas that are more chareidi than they are for instance, have a hat and or jacket that they leave in yeshiva for davening. Those items would have same halacha as taalis and kittel. But nobody is stringent about those. It's an interesting phenomenon.