# Tefilin and other prayer articles in a bathhouse

Tags: halacha, tefilin, tallit-gadol, showering-bathing, holy-objects

Is one allowed to bring Tefilin into a bathhouse or dressing room if he isn’t wearing them?

If not, what if he entered the dressing room while wearing them (which is allowed - OC 45:2), may he leave them there if he took them off afterwards?

Also, what about other articles of prayer, such as a Tallis, Gartel, hat or jacket etc.?

Comment: For tefillin I think the primary issue is kedusha, not articles of prayer

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/110051/taking-tallis-gadol-into-bathroom

Comment: Piskei Teshuvos 21:3 mentions that a gartel is similiar since it used only for prayer. I would assume a hat and jacket are not, since they are worn in other instances as well such as a wedding or formal gathering.

Comment: What do you mean by dressing room? Like in a clothing store?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8735/what-qualities-are-necessary-in-a-halachic-wrapping You’re allowed to bring them into a bathroom as long as they have a double covering. This happens inevitably at an airport where you can’t leave your bags unattended.

Comment: Possible duplicate, which is in turn a duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/130062/bringing-tefillin-into-airport-bathroom